# Different Behavior with wait than await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, wait

We detected a bug in our code, that we assume that is related to a race condition, but we don't understand why is happening. We had the following code

```
private static async Task<bool> IsMigrationPending(DependencyContainer dependencies)
{
    bool isMigrationPending = false;
    await WithCacheLock(MyRedisKey, dependencies, async () =>
    {
        isMigrationPending = await MyFunction();

        LogMessage($"isMigrationPending = {isMigrationPending}").wait();
        return isMigrationPending;
    });
    return isMigrationPending;
}
```

Despite of MyFunction() returns true the method IsMigrationPeding, most of the times we invoke it returned false. Chanigng the code line LogMessage($"isMigrationPending = {isMigrationPending}").wait() to

```
Await LogMessage($"isMigrationPending = {isMigrationPending}")
```

Then it fixed the problem, returning the expected value. For us doesn't make sense that changing a wait to await fix our problem. We expect that wait will block the execution until isMigrationPending value is available, or our assumption is incorrect?

Comment: `await` will block execution until `isMigrationPending` complete too. But it will block only "local" execution.

Comment: what does ```WithCacheLock``` ?

Comment: @tym32167 It creates a Redis Key, if the Redis key exists throws an exception.

Comment: @Fabio I don't understant what you meant by "local" execution?

Comment: @MarcCals, I mean, that execution flow will be returned to the caller of your anonymous method on line `isMigrationPending = await MyFunction();`. And will be continued only when `Task` retuned by `MyFunction` will be complete

Comment: @MarcCals ok, but how this function ```WithCacheLock``` will call passed lambda?